# Ebay Finding API: findCompletedItemsRequest returns active auctions

Tags: xml, ebay-api

I am trying for a while now to get completed auctions using the `findCompletedItemsRequest`. The XML I use for the request is the following:

```
 <findCompletedItemsRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">

    <keywords>fifa 07   </keywords>
    <descriptionSearch>false</descriptionSearch>
    <categoryId>139973</categoryId>
    <itemFilter>
        <name>ListingType</name>
        <!-- <value>FixedPrice</value>-->
        <value>AuctionWithBIN</value> 
        <value>Auction</value>
    </itemFilter>
    <itemFilter>
        <name>HideDuplicateItems</name>
        <value>true</value>     
    </itemFilter>
<!--    <itemFilter>
        <name>SoldItemsOnly</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </itemFilter> -->
    <outputSelector>SellerInfo</outputSelector>
    <outputSelector>AspectHistogram</outputSelector>

    <paginationInput>
        <entriesPerPage>3</entriesPerPage>
        <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
    </paginationInput>

        <itemFilter>
            <name>Condition</name>
            <value>2000</value>
            <value>2500</value>
            <value>3000</value>
            <value>4000</value>
            <value>5000</value>
            <value>6000</value>
        </itemFilter>
</findCompletedItemsRequest>
```

The problem is, that I get just plain still running auctions in the answer.
This is the `itemSearchURL` contained in the answer:

http://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?LH_Auction=1&LH_ItemCondition=2000%7C2500%7C3000%7C4000%7C5000%7C6000&_nkw=fifa+07&_ipg=3&_os=S%7CA%7CD&_pgn=1

Here is the english version of that URL:

http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?LH_Auction=1&LH_ItemCondition=2000%7C2500%7C3000%7C4000%7C5000%7C6000&_nkw=fifa+07&_ipg=3&_os=S%7CA%7CD&_pgn=1

As you can see, the `Completed listings` checkbox is not checked. Can someone tell me the reason for that?

Edit: The solution was easy: I had to put the option X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME = `findCompletedItems` in the header. Before it was set on `findItemsByKeywords`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<!--    <itemFilter>
    <name>SoldItemsOnly</name>
    <value>true</value>
</itemFilter> -->
```

to

```
<itemFilter>
    <name>SoldItemsOnly</name>
    <value>true</value>
</itemFilter>
```

That should fix the issue